# How to use config immutant to implement quartz cluster?

Tags: clojure, immutant

I want to start several web-server, and every server has a quartz instance for avoiding the job being interrupted by restarting the server.

I found that immutant can config the single job .But when i run the server i found that the scheme use the not-cluster config.And i do not know how to config it.

Answer (score 1):

Immutant has built-in support for singelton jobs, but it requires running your application in a [WildFly cluster](http://immutant.org/documentation/current/apidoc/guide-wildfly.html), and does not use Quartz's clustering functionality.

Quartz clustering [requires a JDBC JobStore](http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fre-cls_cluster_configuration.html%23), and Immutant does not currently expose a way to set a JobStore for the scheduler instance. The clustering works by using the database to lock the job - it would not be difficult to implement something similar yourself, by scheduling the same job on every node in the cluster, and using an external store as a synchronization mechanism, allowing the job to run on only one node at a time.

If you truly need the clustering inplementation in Quartz, or need more control over scheduler creation than Immutant provides, please [file an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/IMMUTANT) against Immutant to have those options exposed. In the interim, you could take a look at [Quartzite](http://clojurequartz.info/), I believe it exposes more options for scheduler creation.